# Python - Print specific cookie value from request

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#GET SESSION
s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://www.clos19.com/en-gb/')

#GET CSRFToken
r = requests.get('https://www.clos19.com/en-gb/login')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
CSRFToken = soup.find('input', type='hidden')["value"]
print(soup.find('input', type='hidden')["value"])

#ADD TO CART 
payload = {
    'productCode': '100559',
    'qty': '1',
    'CSRFToken': CSRFToken
}

r = s.post('https://www.clos19.com/en-gb/ajax/addToCart', data=payload, allow_redirects=False)
print(r.status_code)
print(s.cookies.get_dict())
```

Terminal output:

```
{'JSESSIONID': '448858956754C2F8F2DCF1CC4B803833', 'ROUTEID': '.app1', 'mhPreferredCountry': 'GB', 'mhPreferredLanguage': 'en_GB'}
```

How do I print only the JSESSIONID? Therefore the desired printed value would be 448858956754C2F8F2DCF1CC4B803833

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the last line to

```
print(s.cookies['JSESSIONID'])
```

Comment: God so simple haha, thank you for the help - once it allows me I will award answer.